# How to remove digital signature from Outlook VBA?

Tags: vba, outlook

I am trying to remove the digital signature I attached to one of my projects in Outlook 2013.

I deleted the actual signature, I removed the signature from the project, sub folders, everything, and then saved it.

Every time I reopen Outlook, it says that the project has a signature.

Comment: are talking about Digital Certificate for VBA Projects? what window are you using?

Answer (score 0):

To Delete Digital Certificates go to *start > run* and type in the dialog box, type **`certmgr.msc`** and then hit enter

now right click and delete, once you do that go to *VBE Tools Digital Signature and remove it*

[image]

Answer (score 0):

1. Make a backup of all your code by using the "Export" command from the VBE.
2. Delete the old, signed, macro project:

   ```
    %appdata%\Microsoft\Outlook\VbaProject.OTM
   ```
3. Open Outlook, a new VbaProject.OTM file will be created.
4. Import the code in to the new, unsigned, project file.